# adding a delay to changing an image attr after an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so i have a function that is triggered a click of a button (imagine a published/unpublished button)

so as soon as the function loads i change the element to be a loader gif

```
function updateStatus(event, status, element, data, action) {

  //init loader
  $("#" + element).find("img").attr("src", "../../img/images/loader.gif");
```

that works fine

then I do an ajax request where i pass the data (so i can update the database via the rest)

```
var request= $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "../testResponses/status.php",
    data:data

});
```

again that is all good and then when the request is done I can change the image

```
request.done(function(msg) {


        $("#" + element).find("img").attr("src", "../../img/images/status/"+newStatus+".png");
        $("#" + element).attr("data-user-status", newStatus);

});
```

seeing as this is still a proof of concept I want to add a 2 second delay before the loader image disappears and the new status us shown

I tried

```
request.delay(2000).done ...
```

which returned an error and

```
$("#" + element).delay(2000).find("img").attr("src", "../../img/images/status/"+newStatus+".png");
```

which just didnt make any difference..

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to trigger the logic in 2 seconds after you get the request:

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // change the image
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the .delay() queue

```
$("#" + element).delay(2000).delay(function (next) {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "../../img/images/status/" + newStatus + ".png");
    next();
});
```